# sell digital content for free

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We'd like to sell some digital content for free in our app. 
Have we to use In-App Purchase and what type?

How can we set the price that is 0 dollar? and can we change the price for promo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need in-apppurchase for such a strange type of content sale,instead,just use a button that will make an HTTTp request to download that content,or just unlock it inside the app.

You don't need to connect with Apple's server for that,and Apple wouldn't appreciate it too,if you would.So just don't do that.

Comment: in reality, we're selling both paid and free content.and I don't understand what to do: for paid content we use IAP, but in this scheme we can't sell 0 dollars' content, I don't know, how to describe it..

Comment: So make in-app for paid,and a button for free one.It may even look the same,but has different behavior under the hood